Avalonia UI: Same background color for textbox focused, not focused, disabled
Is there a way to make a textbox look the same no matter if it is focused, not focused, disabled, etc?
According to this link: AvaloniaUI
That should be possible by defining styles.
I've tried defining one like this but as soon as the textbox is focused the background color changes:
    <Application.Styles>
    <FluentTheme /> 
    <Style Selector="TextBox">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#323a46"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#323a46"/>            
    </Style>
    <Style Selector="TextBox:focus">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#323a46"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#323a46"/>
    </Style>
    <Style Selector="TextBox:pointerover">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#323a46"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#323a46"/>
    </Style>
    <Style Selector="TextBox:focus-visible">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#323a46"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#323a46"/>
    </Style>
    </Application.Styles>

